# Table and embedded Sparkline

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008, sparklines

I am working with SSRS 2008. I want to show monthly data of different products in a table with a embedded sparkline graph. The table should look like below:

```
Product   Avg Sales  Min Sales Sparkline
P1         100          10      30 days sales sparkline 
P2         500          20      30 days sales sparkline
```

and so on.

I was using matrix for this but it doesn't allow me to bind my sparkline with a different data set other than the matrix data set. How can I get all the data in one dataset?

Comment: Why is this two different Datasets to start with? What is the difference between the two? Do they look at two different date periods?

Comment: I resolved this issue with one data set only using UDFs for aggregate functions.

Comment: @IanPreston Can we use a different data(dataset2) to generate a sparkline within a table with dataset1 in SSRS